# Packing unequal spheres into minimal cuboid

Tags: mathematical-optimization, computational-geometry

There are several non-overlapping spheres in 3D. How to find a  cuboid `Cuboid[{a,b,c}]` containing these spheres with minimal `a+b+c`? Here are my trials with two and three concrete spheres.

(i) The spheres `Sphere[{x,y,z},13]` ang `Sphere[{r,s,t},12]` are done. Here is my code

```
res2 = NMinimize[{a + b + c,  x + 13 <= c && x - 13 >= 0 && y + 13 <= c && y - 13 >= 0 && 
z + 13 <= c && z - 13 >= 0 && r + 12 <= c && r - 12 >= 0 && 
s + 12 <= c && s - 12 >= 0 && t + 12 <= c && 
t - 12 >= 0 && (x - r)^2 + (y - s)^2 + (z - t)^2 >= (13 + 12)^2 &&
 a >= b && b >= c}, {a, b, c, x, y, z, r, s, t}, 
  WorkingPrecision -> 20, MaxIterations -> 400]
```

> `118.30134496888302115, {a -> 39.433781777141207591,  b -> 39.433781662216129186, c -> 39.433781529525684370,  x -> 26.433781527577711100, y -> 26.433781527543169115,  z -> 26.433781527524494303, r -> 12.000024797809696713,  s -> 12.000024797806752675, t -> 12.000024797806996020}}`

The verification is as follows.

```
x + 13 <= a && x - 13 >= 0 && y + 13 <= b && y - 13 >= 0 && 
z + 13 <= c && z - 13 >= 0 && r + 12 <= a && r - 12 >= 0 && 
s + 12 <= b && s - 12 >= 0 && t + 12 <= c && t - 12 >= 0 && a >= b &&
b >= c && (x - r)^2 + (y - s)^2 + (z - t)^2 >= (13 + 12)^2 /. res[[2]]
```

> `True`

However, the above solution is not optimal `Cuboid[{50,26,26}]`. How to find the optimal solution with Mathematica?

(ii) The spheres `Sphere[{x,y,z},13]` ang `Sphere[{r,s,t},12]` and `Sphere[{k,n,h},9/2]` are done. The same question for

```
res3 = NMinimize[{a + b + c, x + 13 <= c && x - 13 >= 0 && y + 13 <= c && y - 13 >= 0 && 
z + 13 <= c && z - 13 >= 0 && r + 12 <= c && r - 12 >= 0 && 
s + 12 <= c && s - 12 >= 0 && t + 12 <= c && 
t - 12 >= 0 && (x - r)^2 + (y - s)^2 + (z - t)^2 >= (13 + 12)^2 &&
 k - 9/2 >= 0 && k + 9/2 <= c && h - 9/2 >= 0 && h + 9/2 <= c && 
n - 9/2 >= 0 && 
n + 9/2 <= 
 c && (x - k)^2 + (y - n)^2 + (z - h)^2 >= (13 + 
    9/2)^2 && (r - k)^2 + (s - n)^2 + (t - h)^2 >= (12 + 9/2)^2 &&
 a >= b && b >= c}, {a, b, c, x, y, z, r, s, t, k, n, h}, 
  WorkingPrecision -> 20, MaxIterations -> 400]
```

> `{118.30129311042972531, {a -> 39.433764379149049236,  b -> 39.433764371039300303, c -> 39.433764360241375774,  x -> 26.433763996833655112, y -> 13.000010247112034705,  z -> 13.000010247112188711, r -> 12.000000035837539518,  s -> 27.433764329963458967, t -> 27.433764358870261060,  k -> 9.1229513952118878652, n -> 10.988012916666727197,  h -> 15.679144217401481948}}`

I may present two references

Stoyan,Y.G.,Scheithauer,G.& Yaskov,G.N.Packing Unequal Spheres into Various Containers.Cybern Syst Anal 52,419-426 (2016). https://doi.org/10.1007/s10559-016-9842-1

Labib Yousef,Contribution à la résolution des problèmes de placement en trois dimensions,Doctorate University de Picardie Jules Verne (France),2017,172 pages.Downloadable from:https://www.theses.fr/2017AMIE0020.pdf

Unfortunately, the linked article is not accessible to me and I don't read French.

Edit. `x+13<=c` instead of `x+13<=a` in `res2`. Sorry for the typo.

Comment: I'm afraid to even think about 9 spheres.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A generalization of @Ulrich Neumann's code:

```
findMinimalBox[rList_] :=
 (
  nSpheres = Length@rList;
  coordsList = Transpose[Array[#, nSpheres] & /@ {x, y, z}];
  dM = Simplify@
    DistanceMatrix[coordsList, 
     DistanceFunction -> SquaredEuclideanDistance];
  rSquareDists = Outer[Plus[#1, #2]^2 &, rList, rList, 1];
  
  eqs = MapThread[GreaterEqual, {dM, rSquareDists}, 2];
  p0 = Position[dM, 0, {2}];
  notOverlapping = Flatten[Delete[eqs, p0]] // DeleteDuplicates;
  
  spheres = MapThread[Sphere[#1, #2] &, {coordsList, rList}];
  
  rb = RegionBounds[RegionUnion @@ spheres];
  
  abc = Map[#[[2]] - #[[1]] &, rb];
  
  mini = NMinimize[{Total[abc], notOverlapping}, Flatten@coordsList];
  abcSoln = abc /. mini[[2]];
  graph = Graphics3D[
   Thread[{Table[ColorData[3, i - 1], {i, nSpheres}], 
     spheres /. mini[[2]]}], Axes -> True, Axes -> {x, y, z}];

  {abcSoln, graph}
  )

findMinimalBox[{12, 13,9/2}]

(*{{26., 49.96, 26.} ,and the graph below}*)
```

I rotated the graph by hand a little to see the three spheres better:
[image: Mathematica graphics]

Trying with 9 spheres (takes about 15 mins on my laptop)

```
SeedRandom[1234];
rList =  RandomInteger[{5, 15}, 9];
findMinimalBox@rList


(*{34.5274, 33.7461, 30.9396}, and graph below}*)
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank's for your support and assistance. Of course I know the generalization but because of the fruitless discussion there was no reason for me to show it.

Comment: Thanks, my original implementation was going to be a lot uglier, but then I saw how you used `RegionBounds` and that my code a lot better looking. Also it doesn't really matter, but I could also fix one of the spheres at the origin to reduce the number of variables by 3 I guess.

Comment: Just caught an error.
$$ $$
 `eqs = MapThread[Equal, {dM, rSquareDists}, 2];`
$$ $$
was supposed to be
$$ $$
`eqs = MapThread[GreaterEqual, {dM, rSquareDists}, 2];`
$$ $$
This makes the code much slower, but not unbearable for 9 spheres (15 mins)

Comment: What is your Mathematica version?

Comment: 13.3.1 for Mac OS X ARM

Comment: Thanks! My version v12.2 doesn't evaluate the case with 9 spheres

Answer (score 5):

Try `RegionBounds` to get the enclosing cuboid `a,b,c` of the two spheres

```
rb = RegionBounds[RegionUnion[Sphere[{x, y, z}, 13], Sphere[{r, s, t}, 12]]];
abc = Map[#[[2]] - #[[1]] &, rb];
mini = NMinimize[{Total[abc], (x - r)^2 + (y - s)^2 + (z - t)^2 >= (13 +12)^2}, {x, y,z, r, s, t}] // Quiet
abc /. mini[[2]] (* sidelengths of the cuboid*)
(*{26., 49.96, 26.}*)

Graphics3D[{Sphere[{x, y, z}, 13], Sphere[{r, s, t}, 12]} /.mini[[2]], Axes -> True, Axes -> {x, y, z}]
```

[image]

Comment: @user64494 How should your code work with undefined `a,b,c`? By the way the solution in my answer seems to be close to the optimum `Cuboid[{0,0,0},{50,26,26}]` which you expects.

Comment: The exact result `mini = Minimize[{Total[
     abc], (x - r)^2 + (y - s)^2 + (z - t)^2 >= (13 + 12)^2}, {x, y, 
    z, r, s, t}] // Quiet
abc /. mini[[2]]` performs `{77 + Sqrt[623], {x -> -Sqrt[623], y -> 0, z -> 0, r -> 0, s -> 1, 
  t -> 1}}` and`{25 + Sqrt[623], 26, 26}` which is too small. Also how about more than two spheres?

Comment: @user64494 I don't know the exact result, though your reply "result is to small"  isn't helpful. My solution idea seems to be not so bad after all. Generalization for more spheres is straight forward (and left up to you)

Comment: I think about it and draw the conclusion that you do find the optimal solution  in the case of two spheres, better than my hypothesis. +1. I don't see a possible generalization on more than two spheres.

Comment: @user64494 The connecting line between the centers of the spheres is not parallel to the cuboid sides! Therefore, the optimum must be less than 50! That's not emotional, that's basic geometry in 3D space. I'm out of this fruitless discussion!

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Aha! I thought it was a bug but I just needed to think more!